# UIPresentationController -- can I update the presented view controller's frame after presentation?

Tags: ios, uipresentationcontroller

I'm using a custom UIPresentationController subclass to manage the presentation of a UIViewController. I'm overriding `- (CGRect)frameOfPresentedViewInContainerView` to provide a frame that is inset from the bounds of the containerView.

Now, after some user action on the presentedViewController, I would like to change the frame of the presentedViewController. My question is: Is there a 'natural' way to do this??

How can I adjust the frame of a presentedViewController after it has been presented?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So the way I went about this was to do the following:

I added implemented the following method from `<UIContentContainer>`:

```
- (void)preferredContentSizeDidChangeForChildContentContainer:(id <UIContentContainer>)container
```

I then simply updated the preferredContentSize on my presentedViewController, got the callback, and animated the frame update within the UIPresentationController.

Answer (score -1):

1. keep instance of NAV or VC in property (save)
2. Present in some x size (can also be change in modalPresentationStyle to popover/fullscreen )
3. [after user action]  dismiss the presented nav or vc
4. present saved VC/NAV  i.e after changing to Y size (can be )

Storing instance means present in same place again.

Use proper animation scroll like below to smooth transition

vc.modalTransitionStyle =  UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;